# C# IDymanicParameters for powershell cmdlet required in both Parent and Child Class

Tags: c#, powershell

We can define [dynamic parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/how-to-declare-dynamic-parameters?view=powershell-7.2) for Powershell commandlets by adding IDynamicParameters and implementing it's GetDynamicParameters() method that creates the dynamic params.

My use-case:
I need to create param2 in Child due to a new requirement, without stopping the creation of param1 in GrandParent.

```
class GrandParent: IDynamicParameters {
   object GetDynamicParameters();  // creates param1
}

class Parent: GrandParent {
// doesn't require dynamic params
}

class Child: Parent, IDynamicParameters
{
   object GetDynamicParameters(); // creates param2
}
```

But I get error [CS0108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108):
`Child.GetDynamicParameters() hides inherited GrandParent.GetDynamicParameters(). Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a virtual non-public implementation you can override instead:

```
class GrandParent: IDynamicParameters
{
    protected virtual object GetDynamicParametersImpl()
    {
        // return dynamic params for grand parent from here
    }

    // no need to change this anywhere else
    public object GetDynamicParameters()
        => GetDynamicParametersImpl();
}

class Parent : GrandParent
{
    protected override object GetDynamicParametersImpl()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child: Parent, IDynamicParameters
{
    protected override object GetDynamicParametersImpl()
    {
        // return dynamic params for child from here
    }
}
```

When `Child.GetDynamicParameters()` is invoked, the call to `GetDynamicParametersImpl` will dispatch the child-specific version